# jest mock express-validator validationResult

Tags: typescript, jestjs, express-validator

Is it possible to mock validationResult, just to prove it was called and that the controller acts accordingly when the validation fails?

```
postSetup: async function (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
  const result = validationResult(req);
  let errors: Array<ValidationError> | false = false;

  if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    errors = result.array();
  } else {
    // processing the inputs
  }

  res.render("setup", {
    // various properties
    errors: errrors
  });
}
```

I just want to import/mock validationResult in my test suite, so that I can prove the errors are checked and written in the response. I don't actually need it to test route validation as that can happen in a different test suite, but is that my only option?

Comment: I wouldn't. You shouldn't mock what you don't own - you have to create and maintain a fairly complicated test double, and expose yourself to the risk that you test against incorrect assumptions (either now or after some future change).

Comment: (This is especially true if you're planning to unit test the controller, because you'd also have to mock Express's request and response.)

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. I'm specifically just wanting to test that the controller acts on any kind of validation error in the correct way, and that res.render is called with the correct object properties. The only other way I think I can test this would be to set up something like supertest against a test version of the app with a fake route, and confirm the html response contains some error messages, but that seemed like I'm testing code a level above the unit I'm interested in. That's why I thought faking the validationResult would be easier, but I guess not.

Comment: I had trouble getting supertest to work though, so the other idea I had was to wrap the validationResult in a Validator class and use that in my controller. Then I can mock my own wrapper class in my test. This seems to work fine, even if it is probably a nasty approach...